# Laravel middleware before WordPress route

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a WordPress installation inside a Laravel project.
It is under the /forum folder inside the public folder, so everytime I go to:

> http://localhost:8000/forum/

It opens the WordPress page.

I'm having trouble running a middleware instance before this route, though.

I want to:

```
Route::GET('/forum', function() { })->middleware('wp_login');
```

Here's my sample middleware:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Log;

class WpForumLogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        Log::debug("test forum lalalala");

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The middleware is set up in the Kernel as such:

```
    ...
    protected $routeMiddleware = [

        ...

        'wp_login' => \App\Http\Middleware\WpForumLogin::class,

    ];
```

How do I run this middleware before running the WordPresse's /forum route?

Thank you.

Comment: What is happening at the moment? Are you being redirected straight to the forum?

Comment: probably you are running out laravel, directly to the wordpress site. in that case there are few things you can do, neither of them optimal

Comment: @TomasCrofty I go to the forum page without ever going through Laravel.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro I'm open to ideas :D If there is a way, please tell me and I'll try to take care of the problems. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly rename the wordpress folder to verify your web request is going through laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a public directory with the same name as your route. The web server will always look for actual files/folders first.

Comment: I assumed so, but isn't there a way to override that behaviour?

Comment: Actually, you can use  `.htaccess` if you're using apache (I'm not sure about nginx) but it's not a good choice, I think probably you can share database for both WordPress and Laravel and do the thing from WordPress site.

Comment: I'd rather not use .htaccess, but if there is no other way, I'll look into it. Thanks for the tip. As for the sharing of the database, we already looked into it and we decided to keep two separate databases for reasons that are too complex to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea of what you can do:

- Rename the "forum" folder (for example "wordpress")
- Now when you go to "/forum" route, laravel will respond, and you can execute your middleware
- In your middleware, after you did your control, you can redirect the user to the new folder (for example "wordpress").

Cons of this solution:

- the user can see the change of url
- if the user go straight to "/wordpress" url he bypasses your middleware. In this case you can check the url of the referrer and act as you want.

This is not the ideal solution, but its a workaround.

Comment: That's exactly what I have implemented right now. As you said, the user can see the url, and if he knows the original url he can bypass the middleware. It's not ideal, but it's the best solution I have for now. Thanks for your input anyway.